# Makefile that can determine using gcc which headers are missing?

Tags: makefile, dependencies, code-generation, build-automation

I have a simple library that generates headers for me and I wish to chain this together in a Makefile.

If a cpp file includes a header file that doesn't exist, it should generate it from a matching source file (should the corresponding file exist). I can't figure out how to do this.

I have tried using gcc -MM to find out the dependencies for each .cpp file ahead of time, but this fails if a header is missing. I need to know which files are missing to attempt to regenerate them.

If I just define a prequisite for the headers for all .cpp files, it will always recompile all of my .cpp files of course.

Any ideas as to how I only regenerate the headers that are missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems the solution can be found using gcc:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Invocation.html

> -MG
>
> In conjunction with an option such as -M requesting dependency
>   generation, -MG assumes missing header
>   files are generated files and adds
>   them to the dependency list without
>   raising an error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried defining a pattern rule to generate each header, e.g.

```
%.hh: %.cpp
    header_generator $^ > $@
```

Comment: That's not the issue. I'm trying to find out which headers included in .cpp files have not been built to create a rule for just these headers.